# Prevent closing of MDI Parent form when child has a message box activated

Tags: winforms, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

The child form checks for user work status (user status is a variable that stores current status of the user. Status can be :- working, pending or completed )

On child formclosing event I checked for user status 
if is not 'Working' then it should close otherwise it should give a message "you haven`t completed your work".
Its working properly when i try to close the child form.
on MDI formclosing event i have called a message "Do you want to exit application". if user says yes application is closed

Now when I close the MDI Parent form first the child shows the message box and then the MDI message box shows.

If i click yes in MDI Messagebox it closes the whole application.

The MDI Form should not get close when i click yes on mdi form message box.

the code this is mdi child form closing event

```
Private Sub frmCalls_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If is_all_working_completed() Then
            Me.Close()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("You cant exit before completing all WORKING  Tickets !")
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub`
```

and this is MDI parent form closing event

```
Private Sub MasterForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

    If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.MdiFormClosing Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If

    If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit ?", "TMS", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) = DialogResult.Yes Then

        Application.Exit()
    Else
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

any help will be appreciated .
thanks in advance

Comment: In your MasterForm_FormClosing event handler insert `If e.Cancel Then Exit Sub` as the first line.  And remove Application.Exit().

Comment: thnks a lot @Hans Passant . It worked !!